# How to disable motion blur for PC Fable III?

Tags: pc, fable-3

How do you disable motion blur? I'm playing on the PC via Steam. What I'm seeing is similiar to the "drunk" blurred vision effect in GTA (but more subtle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it fixed, but found it was the opposite of what many suggest.  In other words, "99" not "0" is the correct minimum threshold to set for blur to be enabled. Meaning, the high threshold makes it never on:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't working for me. Maybe I'm just stupids with the program files, but I can't save anything I do in the xml file. It says access denied. And I don't have an option to run as administrator so I really don't know what to do. I'm so frustrated because no one else seems to be having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file *VideoOptionsConfig.xml* file usually located at *Steam\steamapps\common\fable 3*

```
<IntSettings>
    <BloomMinimumEffectsDetail>0</BloomMinimumEffectsDetail>
    <RadialBlurMinimumEffectsDetail>0</RadialBlurMinimumEffectsDetail>
    <DepthOfFieldMinimumEffectsDetail>2</DepthOfFieldMinimumEffectsDetail>
    <MotionBlurMinimumEffectsDetail>0</MotionBlurMinimumEffectsDetail>
    <TemporalAAMinimumEffectsDetail>3</TemporalAAMinimumEffectsDetail>
    <TemporalAAMinimumEffectsDetailMGPU>99</TemporalAAMinimumEffectsDetailMGPU>
    <SSAAMinimumEffectDetail>3</SSAAMinimumEffectDetail>
    <SaturationMaskMinimumEffectsDetail>0</SaturationMaskMinimumEffectsDetail>
    <SpecularMinimumShaderDetail>0</SpecularMinimumShaderDetail>
    <EnvMappingMinimumShaderDetail>0</EnvMappingMinimumShaderDetail>
    <RainAndSnowMinimumEffectDetail>1</RainAndSnowMinimumEffectDetail>
    <FresnelMinimumShaderDetail>1</FresnelMinimumShaderDetail>
    <TieredOcclusionMaximumModelDetail>3</TieredOcclusionMaximumModelDetail>
```

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20110824202413/http://lionhead.com/forums/p/303677/3677076.aspx)

Comment: I got it fixed, but found it was the opposite of what many suggest. In other words, "99" not "0" is the correct minimum threshold to set for blur to be enabled.

Comment: well, quite strange but at least you were able to solve you problem ;)